# Is a global PHP CONSTANT available inside of a Class file?

Tags: php, constants

Is a global PHP CONSTANT available inside of a Class file?

```
define('SITE_PATH', 'C:/webserver/htdocs/somefolder/');
```

Then in my class file I try this

```
public $debug_file = SITE_PATH. 'debug/debug.sql';
```

This does not seem to work though,

> Parse error: parse error, expecting
>   `','' or`';'' in
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\somefolder\includes\classes\Database.class.php
>   on line 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an expression in a class declaration.

I would suggest passing the path in:

```
public function __construct($path)
{
    $this->debug_path = $path;
}
```

This gives you more flexibility if you ever want to change the path, you don't have to change a constant, just what you pass in.

Or you could create multiple objects that all have different paths. This is useful if it is an autoloader class, as you might want to have it load multiple directories.

```
$autoloader = new Autoload(dirname(SYS_PATH));
$autoloader->register_loader();

class Autoload
{
    public $include_path = "";

    public function __construct($include_path="")
    {
        // Set the Include Path
        // TODO: Sanitize Include Path (Remove Trailing Slash)
        if(!empty($include_path))
        {
            $this->include_path = $include_path;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->include_path = get_include_path();
        }

        // Check the directory exists.
        if(!file_exists($this->include_path))
        {
            throw new Exception("Bad Include Path Given");
        }
    }
    // .... more stuff ....
}
```

Comment: And the comments means that I gave you source code from my project instead of recreating it. Yay!

Comment: get_include_path() can return multiple paths separated by the OS specific path separator. So your call to file_exists will fail if multiple paths are defined, but are valid paths individually.

Answer (score 5):

I second what the others said. Since $debugFile seems an optional dependency, I'd suggest to initialize a sane default on creation of the class and then allow changing it by setter injection when needed, e.g.

```
define('SITE_PATH', 'C:/webserver/htdocs/somefolder/');

class Klass
{
    protected $_debugFile;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_debugFile = SITE_PATH. 'debug/debug.sql' // default
    }
    public function setDebugFile($path)
    {
        $this->_debugFile = $path // custom
    }
}
```

Note that injecting SITE_PATH, instead of hardcoding it, would be even better practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use expression (.) in field initializer. [See example one in PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: I see, so I should basicly create ANOTHER new constant with the full path to my debug file?

Comment: Well .. you can .. it just has to contain literal strings.

Comment: and @Jasondavis, Yes. But you could just, on initialization of the class pass it a path. That would allow you to use multiple paths (multiple objects) or change the path later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however, property values defined at compile time cannot be expressions.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php