# PHP constant in static variable

Tags: php, variables, static, constants

I need to use PHP constant in a static variable but I discover today that it's not possible : [Is a global PHP CONSTANT available inside of a Class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082935/is-a-global-php-constant-available-inside-of-a-class-file)

```
define("TABLE_PREFIX", "TEST_");

class Test {

    private static $sql_query = "select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."USER";

    public static function show_query1() {
        echo "My first test";
        echo self::$sql_query;
    }

    public static function show_query2() {
        echo "My second test";
        echo self::$sql_query;
    }

}


Test::show_query1();
Test::show_query2();
```

I don't want to pass the constant as an argument to the static function and I don't want to declare $sql_query in each static function.

What is the best way to to it ?

EDIT : add demo = http://codepad.org/aqzj2TJh

Comment: You can use the constant just fine. What you cannot do is use an expression like `"concatenated"."strings"`.

Comment: You found the right answer already, you just misunderstood it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar : classic getter and setter only works in object context. I don't want to define a static setter and to call it each time... (if there is another solution)

Comment: @Jon : You can use the constant just fine => so why do I get this error : "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' on line 7" (see the demo link I've added)

Comment: @deceze : Can you explain please ?

Comment: @Matth `private static $foo = CONSTANT` works fine, `private static $foo = 'string' . CONSTANT` doesn't! The problem is the `.` (an *expression*), not the constant.

Comment: @deceze : Yes you're right, I know it, but I'm looking for an alternative... What is best other way to do the same thing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public static variable value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500732/public-static-variable-value)

Comment: @deceze : Thank you, it explains the problem and why it appears but it doesn't answer the question :  what is the best way to work around this... In your answer you initialize the static variable in the static function, I don't want this. I'm surprised there is no "clean" solution... :(

Comment: There is no *other* solution, or at least nothing else that will conform to your idea of "clean". Take it or leave it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same  with other way.

```
define("TABLE_PREFIX", "TEST_");
define("TEST_TABLE_QUERY", "select * from ".TABLE_PREFIX."USER");
class Test {

    private static $sql_query = TEST_TABLE_QUERY;

    public static function show_query1() {
        echo "My first test";
        echo self::$sql_query;
   }

    public static function show_query2() {
        echo "My second test";
        echo self::$sql_query;
   }

}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you Amit Kumar Sharma, it works but my sql queries are very big and I get word wrap inside them...

Comment: In this case you may use %s in the define("TEST_TABLE_QUERY", "select %s TABLE WHERE %s "); And than can use sprinf() in your class